# "segmentation fault" probably issued by memory allocation in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gdb

In this code I would like to find the longest word in a sentence
where I stop by a segmentation fault which I think is due to memory allocation in the function longestEvenWord() is going to return the "res"variable; seems the res is not assign correctly. By running gdb I get following error

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x0, format=0x400d22 "%s\n", 
ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdca8) at vfprintf.c:1275
1275    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Here is the code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readline();
char* longestWord();

int main(){
  FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w");
  char* sentence = readline();
  char* res = longestWord(sentence);
  fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", res);
  fclose(fptr);
  return 0;
}

char* readline() {
  size_t alloc_length = 1024;
  size_t data_length = 0;
  char* data = malloc(alloc_length);
  while (true) {
    char* cursor = data + data_length;
    char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);
    if (!line){ 
         break; 
    }
    data_length += strlen(cursor);
    if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n'){ 
         break; 
    }
    size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
    data = realloc(data, new_length);
    if (!data) { break; }
    alloc_length = new_length;
  }
  if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
    data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
  }
  data = realloc(data, data_length);
  return data;
}


char* longestWord(char* sentence) {
 char res[134] = "00";
 char word[134];
 char s[134];
 strcpy(s, sentence);
 memset(word,0,strlen(word));
 int l, c = 0, max = -1;
 l = strlen(s);
 for(int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++){
    if(s[i] != ' '){
        word[c]= s[i] ;
        c++;
    }else{
          if(c > max) {
             word[c+1]='\0';
             max = c;
             strcpy(res, word);
         }
        c = 0;
        memset(word,0,strlen(word));
    }
 }
 if(c > max) {
      max = c;
      strcpy(res, word);
 }
 return res;
}
```

Comment: You cant return array, you must return pointer. res = malloc(SIZE);

Answer (score 1):

Is there any possibility that this line is your problem?
      FILE* fptr = fopen(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"), "w”);

fopen can fail, and return a NULL for many reasons unrelated to memory corruption.  Maybe add a line, just after the above one like:

```
if (fptr == NULL) { perror(“fopen failed”); exit(1); }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an article at Wikipedia, [Dangling Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), that explains the problem of your code well.

In short, all automatic variables lose their memory control after returning from the function. Hence it cannot be assumed that the address at which you stored some data would remain intact; another function might have overrided the place, for example.

You can make `res` dynamic using `malloc` and initialize with `strcpy` as below.

```
char *res = (char *)malloc(134 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(res, "00");
```

Make sure to deallocate dynamic variables after using them, otherwise they will cause memory leak, though in your program it won't be a problem because it just ends after printing `res`.

Comment: Thanks. But still get the same problem I think it could not return the res to the main code!

Comment: @teri: After inspecting `longestEvenWord`, I found `memset(word,0,strlen(word));` odd for `word` is not initialized at the moment of `strlen` call. Replace this with `word[0] = '\0;' and tell me if it works.